# Create Slack Message Destination in Salesforce from Slack

Tags: slack-salesforce-app

Slack for Salesforce has an invocable action for Flow to send a message to a Slack channel or user. The Channel or User id is required (and it's not the Salesforce User Id, it's a slack Id), and those Channel and User destinations must be saved as slackv2__Message_Destination__c records in Salesforce.

Setting up those Message Destinations is done by an admin in the Slack Setup app. However, I'd like to be able to have them created by a Slack User, pushed into Salesforce from the Slack end. Or, at the very least, by a Standard User in Salesforce.

For example, a Sales Rep might create a new Opportunity and want to create a slack channel for an account team 'swarm'. They could easily create the channel in Slack, but then it's not set up as a Message Destination. Currently, an admin would have to create it.

I think there's an Apex action to create a Slack Channel, so maybe I create a screen flow accessible to the Sales rep, which creates the channel on Slack, then creates the Message Destination -- though I'll need to figure out how to retrieve the channel Id.

There's an LWC modal that's part of the Slack Setup app where it can search for existing Channels in your workspace. I'd love to use that (or its methods), but it's all hidden in the managed package. (Is there an open source git for this?)

Hoping to do this with the actions built into Slack for Salesforce, but I'm comfortable with api calls if needed.

Has anyone done this yet? Looking for advice, and or, more documentation.